# Commercial Audio Attenuators

Tags: audio

Having investigated producing my own audio attenuators, how are commercial (off the shelf) passives produced? Namely how are an individuals I/P - O/P characteristic requirements matched by these commercial units?
I know my device input Impedance but not the feed device output, therefore am struggling to "get it right".

---

Thanks to all concerned, this info is what I needed but still beggars the question of how, if input/output impedance (of devices) values are essential, are the values of commercial devices (Typically Rothwell) made if they have no starting point reference too end users I/O impedance values. It can only be assumed that they are marketed on the basis of guesswork.
I digress, Thanks for the clear instructions I can now forge ahead with the project in the knowledge that they will be what I want in the end.

Comment: An signal attenuator for audio can be made with 2 resistors, OK 4 if you want stereo. Maybe you're talking about an adjustable attenuator ? Include a link to an example of a commercial product so that we get an idea what you mean.

Comment: Addressing the second part of your question, standard attenuators are manufactured for standard impedance values; e.g., 600 ohms for audio or 50 ohms for RF.

Answer (score 1):

Modern audio is generally voltage transfer not power transfer, so sources are assumed to be low impedance and loads high impedance, typically for line level a competent source will be a hundred ohms (Pro audio) to maybe a k ohm (Unbal domestic junk), and loads are usually 10K or there about.

For mic levels you can generally roll with 150 ohm source and maybe 2k or so for the load, but remember that your pad needs to pass phantom in a sane way.

One thing you will find is that for anything more then about 10dB or so you can probably find a set of resistors where the exact source and load make very little difference, for example an L pad for 10dB could be something like 3.3K series and 1K shunt, a few hundred ohms of source impedance makes little difference to that as does swinging the load from say 10K to 1Meg...
By the time you are doing 20dB (10K series, 1K shunt) pretty much any sane source and load Z will make only a fraction of a dB of difference, and that is what the volume knob is for.

600 ohms has not been a major thing in audio in the last 40 odd years, it was only ever an import from the phone companies who deal with long enough lines for it to matter.

Incidentally, Canford are cheaper then Rothwell...

Comment: Superb! This explains more than I had hoped. I was somewhat concerned that not getting it right would cause some major unforeseen problem (damage). Will now crack on with getting the Wee Blighters sorted, Thanks a million (also for the price saving tip).

Comment: Looks like I slightly stuffed up the resistor values, should be ~2k2 and 1k for 10dB and ~9k and 1k for 20dB L pads, but in practice exact values are not exactly important most of the time. These are for unbalanced L pads, but the math is not hard for other variants.

Answer (score 0):

To make an impedance matched attenuator you may need to use 3 or 4 resistors per channel in either a pi or T configuration.

If you want to find out the output impedance connect a resistor to the output and measure the current while applying a 1KHz sign wave to the input of that source, than change the resistor to half the value and measure the current again the current will not be exactly twice. Use that difference to calculate the output stage impedance.